# Minimum iOS deployment target with Facebook SDK 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I wish to use Facebook sdk version 3.2 in my iOS application but I couldn't find the minimum target iOS that it will support.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your desired target?  I can say for sure that it supports iOS 5 as a minimum target.

Comment: @SeamusCampbell I need at least 4.3 and if you are correct than does 3.1 support it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SDK Page](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/concepts/ios-build-distribute-promote/):

> ### iOS 6 integration
>
> The Facebook SDK for iOS offers full, native integration with iOS 6. For Login and Feed posting, this means you have the ability to pop-up a native dialog box rather than fast-app-switching to the Facebook iOS App or Mobile Safari. This experience is less disruptive for the user and significantly increases conversion. **Just enable Login with Facebook and the SDK will ensure your apps work seamlessly on all iOS versions 4.0 and later.**